# Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf vs. obj.prototype.isPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, prototype

*I am not looking forward the differences between one and the other. Airbnb already does a great job explaining about it [on the style guides repository](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--prototype-builtins).*

Considering a trivial class and its implementation like the following:

```
class C1 {}
const c1Imp = new C1();
```

Where `.prototype` should be inherited from [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Why isn't the following equivalent?

```
console.info(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1, c1Imp)); // false
console.info(C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c1Imp)); // true
```

```js
 (() => {
 class C1 {}
 const c1Imp = new C1();

 console.info(c1Imp.constructor.name);
 console.info(`${Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1, c1Imp)} (should be true)`);
 console.info(`${C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c1Imp)} (should be true)`);
  
 class C2 {}
 const c2Imp = new C2();
  
 console.info(c2Imp.constructor.name);
 console.info(`${Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1, c2Imp)} (should be false)`);
 console.info(`${C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c2Imp)} (should be false)`);
})();
```

*PS: the question title isn't very clear, feel free to edit as appropriate.*

Comment: `Object.prototype` refers to a very specific instance of `object`. `C1.prototype` also refers to an `object`, but not the same actual instance as `Object.prototype`. Keep *types* separate from *instances*. Two instances can be the same type, but be separate objects.

Comment: You're effectively calling `C1.isPrototypeOf(c1Imp))` which is false because `C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c1Imp)` is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1.prototype, c1Imp) // true
```

In your first example, you were calling the `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf` method on `C1` itself, while in the second example, you were calling `isProtoTypeOf` on the `C1.prototype`. **It's just some tricky semantics.**

The fix as I showed above is to called `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf` on the `C1.prototype` itself.

Check out the updated snippet:

```js
 (() => {
 class C1 {}
 const c1Imp = new C1();

 console.info(c1Imp.constructor.name);
 console.info(`${Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1.prototype, c1Imp)} (should be true)`);
 console.info(`${C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c1Imp)} (should be true)`);
  
 class C2 {}
 const c2Imp = new C2();
  
 console.info(c2Imp.constructor.name);
 console.info(`${Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(C1, c2Imp)} (should be false)`);
 console.info(`${C1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c2Imp)} (should be false)`);
})();
```